# Change property handler for .avi

Tags: c#, windows, shell, delphi, registry

I made property handler extension (Like a "Title" property column) for some file types but when I want to register Shell extension for real types like avi or 3gp extension wont work but another types like avi1 or 3gp1 works like a charm.
I search regisrery and PropertyHandler added for avi and avi1 but for avi found a key named "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\SystemPropertyHandlers" that contain values for 3gp and avi and it has a different value than my handler and I cant change or delete this value.

I want to ask how can I change these type property handler in SystemPropertyHandlers?For example add Title property for avi file.

**EDIT:**
This is the code if help to solve problem :

```
type
  TPropertyStoreExtension6 = class(TdecShellPropertyStoreExtension)
  protected
    class function GetClassID: TCLSID; override;
    class function GetDescription: UnicodeString; override;
    procedure FillProgIDList(AList: TStrings); override;
    procedure Clear; override;
    function GetPropertyCount: Integer; override;
    function GetPropertyKey(AIndex: Integer): TPropertyKey; override;
    function GetPropertyName(AIndex: Integer): UnicodeString; override;
    procedure LoadDataFromFile(const AFileName: UnicodeString;
      AOpenMode: DWORD); override;
    procedure LoadDataFromFolder(const AFolderName: UnicodeString); override;
    function GetAvailablePropertyCount: Integer; override;
    function AvailableIndexToIndex(AIndex: Integer): Integer; override;
    function GetPropertyValue(AIndex: Integer): OleVariant; override;
    procedure CommitToFile(const AFileName: UnicodeString;
      AOpenMode: DWORD); override;
  private
    Filename: UnicodeString;
  end;

implementation

uses SysUtils, Variants;


class function TPropertyStoreExtension6.GetClassID: TCLSID;
begin
  Result := SID_TPropertyStoreExtension6;
end;

class function TPropertyStoreExtension6.GetDescription: UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := 'Your handler description';
end;

procedure TPropertyStoreExtension6.FillProgIDList(AList: TStrings);
begin
  AList.Add(UnicodeStringToString('.avi'));
  AList.Add(UnicodeStringToString('.avi1'));
end;

procedure TPropertyStoreExtension6.Clear;
begin
  inherited Clear;
end;

function TPropertyStoreExtension6.GetPropertyCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 3;
end;

function TPropertyStoreExtension6.GetPropertyKey(AIndex: Integer): TPropertyKey;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Result, SizeOf(Result));
  case AIndex of
    0:
      Result := PKEY_Title;
  end;
end;

function TPropertyStoreExtension6.GetPropertyName(AIndex: Integer)
  : UnicodeString;
begin
  Result := '';
  case AIndex of
    0:
      Result := 'Title';

  end;
end;

procedure TPropertyStoreExtension6.LoadDataFromFile(const AFileName
  : UnicodeString; AOpenMode: DWORD);
begin

end;

procedure TPropertyStoreExtension6.LoadDataFromFolder(const AFolderName
  : UnicodeString);
begin

end;

function TPropertyStoreExtension6.GetAvailablePropertyCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1
end;

function TPropertyStoreExtension6.AvailableIndexToIndex
  (AIndex: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := AIndex
end;

function TPropertyStoreExtension6.GetPropertyValue(AIndex: Integer): OleVariant;
begin

  case AIndex of

    0:
      Result := 'Title is here';
  end;
end;

procedure TPropertyStoreExtension6.CommitToFile(const AFileName: UnicodeString;
  AOpenMode: DWORD);
begin

end;

initialization

TPropertyStoreExtension6.Register;

end.
```

**EDIT :**
I just test [this](https://superuser.com/questions/601505/why-cant-i-change-window-7-registry-key) way but this error happen:

> Unable to save permission changes on SystemPropertyHandlers.

**EDIT :**
I change permission like [here](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-take-ownership-permission-of-a-registry-key-in-windows/) and change key value but still my property handler wont work for avi.

**EDIT :**
I **solved** problem with deleting .avi from "SystemPropertyHandlers" and now everything works.But I still have question how can I done this without deleting and most important how done this in user PC?

Comment: I don't quite understand what are you saying. Are you trying to register your application as default one that open certain file type? If it is so are you aware that each file type can have multiple programs set to open them and only one of them can be set as default? So it is posible that you are adding your program to the list of one that can open that specific file type but not set it as default. Also I belive that application needs to be run with elevated privilegies in order to change the default program for opening certain file type if another one is already set.

Comment: Anywhay it would be best if you show us your current code that fails to do what you expect so we can find what are you doing wrong.

Comment: No.A property handler like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx .And its not a code problem exactly.Just check that registry key,It doesn't allow any change.

Comment: Are you wunning your prgoram with normal or elevated privilegies? Becouse from what I see in your question you are trying to modify part of registry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE brach which does require elevated acces for any modifications. You even need to start Regedit.exe with elevated privilegies (Run As Administrator) to modify that part of registry.

Comment: Sure I am.But just error,I can add other key and change values but just cant change this key.Just test your self that key and test changing .avi

Comment: - *".. without deleting .."* - Probably by taking ownership of the key first to be able to change security settings.

Comment: So how can I do this in app?Just registry editing with administrator rights didn't work.